# How to get the at key, hash and quotes on an external microsoft keyboard macbook pro?

Tags: macos, macbook-pro

I am using a microsoft external keyboard with my macbook pro with Snow Leopard.

The keyboard is a British setup so that the label for the number 2 is the AT symbol and switched with the double quotes ley as well as a the hash key